SP SAML initiatd flow with picketlink with JBOSS EAP 7.3
I'm trying to integrate an EAR application with an external IdP (in my case a dockerized keycloak (n port 8180)..just to confirm the completion of the flow).
The application was corrected integrated with the old external IdP when the application was in the EAP 6.4.
I want to implement a SP initiated flow so when an user try to get the resource (SP on port 8080) he/she should be redirected to IdP for the login. After the login the IdP will give the SAML assertion wiith all claims/attributes that th application need.
The Application Server seems to be configured in correct way. In fact in standalone.xml there's the snippet:
 <security-domain name="sp" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.jboss.auth.SAML2LoginModule" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>

as result of CLI explained here
I've exported from Idp the idp-metadata and sp-metadata and in WEB-INF/classes of the war (inside th EAR) I'v the two files:
idp-metadata.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<EntitiesDescriptor
    Name="urn:mace:shibboleth:testshib:two"
    xmlns:shibmd="urn:mace:shibboleth:metadata:1.0"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare">
    <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:KeyName>dfmocdmyXxhlL0uMVRpqKw_UKNV7SOx4SRCaSrXmofU</ds:KeyName>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>
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
</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare/protocol/saml/resolve" index="0"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare/protocol/saml"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare/protocol/saml"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare/protocol/saml"/>
        <md:NameIDFormat>
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare/protocol/saml"/>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare/protocol/saml"/>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare/protocol/saml"/>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare/protocol/saml"/>
    </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>

</EntitiesDescriptor>

sp-metadata.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<EntitiesDescriptor
    Name="urn:mace:shibboleth:testshib:two"
    xmlns:shibmd="urn:mace:shibboleth:metadata:1.0"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
    <!-- SP metadata -->
    <md:EntityDescriptor
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    entityID="client_portaleImmobiliare" ID="ID_e675b358-5a20-466d-822d-d09dcde7cdb4">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="ERROR:ENDPOINT_NOT_SET"></md:SingleLogoutService>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="ERROR:ENDPOINT_NOT_SET" isDefault="true" index="1"></md:AssertionConsumerService>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
</EntitiesDescriptor>


the contents of the two files are generated on IdP side (keycloak).
In keycloak I've also exported the signing keys n jks format to accomplish the trust phase between SP and Idp.
In web.xml I've this snippet configuration for auth:
<context-param>
        <param-name>CONFIG_PROVIDER</param-name>
        <param-value>org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.config.SPPostMetadataConfigurationProvider</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    
    <!-- Define Sesion Timeout -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Define a Security Constraint on this Application -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>portaleImmobiliare</web-resource-name>
            
            <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern> 
            <url-pattern>/authorization/*</url-pattern> 
            <url-pattern>/property/*</url-pattern> 
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
    
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        
        <realm-name>portaleImmobiliare</realm-name>
    </login-config>


in jboss-web.xml I've:
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>portaleImmobiliare</context-root>
    <security-domain>sp</security-domain>
</jboss-web>

and in jboss-deployment-structure:
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.picketlink" services="import"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

My picketlink.xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<PicketLink xmlns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:config:2.1">
<!--   
    <PicketLinkSP xmlns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:config:2.1" 
    ServerEnvironment="tomcat" 
    BindingType="POST" 
    SupportsSignatures="true" 
    LogOutPage="/logout.xhtml">
-->     
      <PicketLinkSP xmlns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:config:2.1"
        BindingType="POST"
        ErrorPage="/notavailable.html"
        LogOutPage="/logout.jsp"
        IDPUsesPostBinding="true"
        SupportsSignatures="true">

        <IdentityURL>${idp.url::http://localhost:8180}</IdentityURL>
        <ServiceURL>${portaleImmobiliare.url::http://localhost:8080/portaleImmobiliare}</ServiceURL>  
  
        <KeyProvider ClassName="org.picketlink.identity.federation.core.impl.KeyStoreKeyManager">
        
        <Auth Key="KeyStoreURL" Value="/keystore/keystore_sign.jks" />
            <Auth Key="KeyStorePass" Value="portaleImmobiliare_store" />
            <Auth Key="SigningKeyPass" Value="portaleImmobiliare_key" />
            <Auth Key="SigningKeyAlias" Value="client_portaleImmobiliare" />
            <!-- <ValidatingAlias Key="http://localhost:8180/realms/portaleImmobiliare" Value="portaleImmobiliare" />-->
        </KeyProvider>
    </PicketLinkSP>
    <Handlers xmlns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:handler:config:2.1">
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2LogOutHandler" />
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2AuthenticationHandler">
            <Option Key="NAMEID_FORMAT" Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" />
            <Option Key="AUTHN_CONTEXT_CLASSES" Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:GBS:PCF" />
            <Option Key="ASSERTION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME" Value="SAML_ASSERTION" />
        </Handler>
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2AttributeHandler">
            <Option key="ATTRIBUTE_KEYS" Value="uid" />
            <Option key="ATTRIBUTE_KEYS" Value="groupMembership" />
        </Handler>
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2SignatureGenerationHandler" />
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2SignatureValidationHandler" />
    </Handlers>
</PicketLink>


The deployment success, but when I try to open the application I've this error:
10:35:14,560 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-4) Matched prefix path /portaleImmobiliare for path /portaleImmobiliare
10:35:14,562 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Security constraints for request /portaleImmobiliare are [SingleConstraintMatch{emptyRoleSemantic=PERMIT, requiredRoles=[]}]
10:35:14,562 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Attempting to authenticate /portaleImmobiliare, authentication required: false
10:35:14,562 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.security.impl.CachedAuthenticatedSessionMechanism@1664c2af for /portaleImmobiliare
10:35:14,563 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletFormAuthenticationMechanism@25af5e83 for /portaleImmobiliare
10:35:14,563 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Authentication result was ATTEMPTED for /portaleImmobiliare
10:35:14,573 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-4) Matched prefix path /portaleImmobiliare for path /portaleImmobiliare/
10:35:14,573 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Security constraints for request /portaleImmobiliare/ are [SingleConstraintMatch{emptyRoleSemantic=AUTHENTICATE, requiredRoles=[]}]
10:35:14,573 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Authenticating required for request HttpServerExchange{ GET /portaleImmobiliare/}
10:35:14,574 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Setting authentication required for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /portaleImmobiliare/}
10:35:14,574 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Attempting to authenticate /portaleImmobiliare/authorization/profiles.xhtml, authentication required: true
10:35:14,574 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.security.impl.CachedAuthenticatedSessionMechanism@1664c2af for /portaleImmobiliare/
10:35:14,574 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletFormAuthenticationMechanism@25af5e83 for /portaleImmobiliare/
10:35:14,575 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Sending authentication challenge for HttpServerExchange{ GET /portaleImmobiliare/}
10:35:14,575 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-5) Serving login form null for HttpServerExchange{ GET /portaleImmobiliare/}
10:35:14,575 DEBUG [io.undertow.session] (default task-5) Created session with id dwhrT0dStpA6QHt5xykVKVEy8tk2JvwtDAKCNGbx for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /portaleImmobiliare/}
10:35:14,576 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception handling request to /portaleImmobiliare/: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getRequestDispatcher(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:968) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletFormAuthenticationMechanism.servePage(ServletFormAuthenticationMechanism.java:160) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.FormAuthenticationMechanism.sendChallenge(FormAuthenticationMechanism.java:176) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$ChallengeSender.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:301) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$ChallengeSender.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:319) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$ChallengeSender.access$300(SecurityContextImpl.java:284) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.sendChallenges(SecurityContextImpl.java:130) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:102) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:107) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:92) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_251]

... as you sen in the log:
Serving login form null for HttpServerExchange{ GET /portaleImmobiliare/}
seems there's something missing in xml fils configuration of picketlink/undertow that non initialize the beans needed fo SP initiated flw correctly. Any Idea of what I mistake in the configuration?
I've tried different configuration...
What I expected is a redirect to IdP login page if I try to access to SP

even if is SP initiated flow you've to define the section form-login-config in web.xml ( don't know why) ... so the NullPointerException is avoided but when I try to access the application it try to redirect me to jsp/logn.jsp page (that not exists)...
I think the problem is derived by the EAR structured deployed to jboss ...
In fact the project picketlink-federation-saml-sp-with-metadata in https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts works correctly. Replicated the same structures and files in my project the redirection to IdP doesn't work ...
